# How many Green's functions exist for a given differential operator?

Tags: boundary-conditions, differential-equations, greens-functions

Let's say we have a scalar field $\psi(x)$ that satisfies a field equation

\begin{equation}
\nabla^\mu \nabla _\mu \psi (x) + V(x) \psi (x)=\rho(x)
\end{equation}

where $V(x)$ is some potential and $\rho(x)$ is a source for the scalar field. $\psi$ can be expressed as an integral over a Green's function satisfying

\begin{equation}
\nabla^\mu \nabla_\mu G(x,x') + V(x) G(x,x')=\delta(x-x')
\end{equation}

I understand that there exist different solutions for this equation. In particular, one can find a retarded Green's function that vanishes if $x'$ is in the future of $x$, an advance Green's function that vanishes if $x'$ is in the past of $x$. There are also symmetric or antitymmetric Green's functions, Green's functions that vanish when $x$ and $x'$ are time-like separated, etc.

My question is: Is there any systematic way of knowing if any given Green's function exists? Does the potential $V(x)$ need to satisfy some properties? Are they all related by adding a homogenous solution to the field equations?

Comment: I feel this would actually be better answered at [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com) than here, or at least as a cross posted post. Just seems like much more a question about differential equations than physics itself.

Comment: Any two solutions differ by a solution to the homogeneous equation. Therefore the space of solutions can be parameterized by picking a reference solution and adding a solution to the homogeneous equation. The mathematical problem is therefore to find the dimension of the space of solutions to the homogeneous differential equation. Of course this depends on the particular differential operator.

Comment: @Gold: how do we know that any solutions exist in the first place for an arbitrary $V(x)$? Your reasoning relies on the existence of at least one Green's function.  I'm sure there's some argument for it but it's not coming to me immediately.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, yes, that's my point when I say that the answer depends on the particular differential operator. For OP's title question to make sense I assume a solution exists, but I think it could as well not be the case. I'm unaware of an existence result for arbitrary $V(x)$.

Comment: Assuming the spacetime is globally hyperbolic ( in particular Minkowski spacetime), the operator is *normally hyperbolic independently of the choice of $V$* (assumed to be smooth), thus it is *Green hyperbolic*. In summary **it uniquely admits causal Green functions, which are also continuous in the relevant topologies.** The point is that here the imposed conditions are not standard, for that reason the issue is difficult. I do not think that Mathematics is the right place where asking it. Here is the right place, since it is an mathematical physics issue. I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer, but I think it is however informative.

Consider a globally hyperbolic smooth spacetime $(M,g)$, for instance Minkowski one.
There, a 2nd order linear differential operator $P: C^\infty(M) \to C^\infty(M)$ is called **normally hyperbolic** if, in local coordinates
$$(P\psi)(x) = g^{ab}(x)\partial_a\partial_b \psi(x) + h^a(x)\partial_a\psi(x) + k(x) \psi(x)\:.$$
assuming the functions $h^a$ and $k$ to be smooth. Clearly your operator is of this form. An extension  of this notion can be given for operators acting on vector bundles on $M$ and satisfying certain further natural requirments (see these amazing  lecture [notes](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Christian-Baer-5/publication/314096823_Lecture_Notes_Geometric_Wave_Equations/links/58ef296fa6fdcc61cc1284fa/Lecture-Notes-Geometric-Wave-Equations.pdf) by C. Baer or the introductive parts of a recent  [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00029-023-00860-z) of mine and coworkers, especially section 3).

A normally hyperbolic operator always satisfyes an *existence and uniqueness theorem for the associated Cauchy problem*. Furthermore it always admits a (unique and continuous) couple of **causal Green functions**. They are maps
$$G_\pm ; C^\infty_0(M)\to C^\infty(M)$$
(here and henceforth $C^\infty_0(M)$ is the space of compactly supported real smooth functions on $M$) satisfying

- $G_\pm(f)$ "respectively vanishes outside the causal past/future of the support of $f$" (this requirement can be made mathematically precise in terms of standard causality notions on a Lorentzian manifold)
- $PG_\pm f = G_\pm P f = f$ if $f\in C_0^\infty(M)$.

The second condition is the standard one written in terms of Dirac delta by physicists, when writing $G_\pm$ in terms of formal kernels (distributions)
$$(G_\pm\psi)(x) = \int_M G_\pm(x,y) f(y) d\mu_g(y)$$

Evidently,

(a) every linear combination  $pG_+ +q G_-$ with $p,q \in [0,1]$ and $p+q =1$ is still a Green function as it satisfies the second condition written above;

(b) if $G,G'$ satisfy that condition, then $P(G-G')=0$ so that $E:= G-G' ; C_0^\infty(M) \to C^\infty(M)$ is a map associating compactly supported smooth functions with solutions of the **omogeneous** wave equation
$$P\psi = 0\:.$$

For instance the so callse **causal propagator** $E:= G_+-G_-$ is surjective onto the space of solutions of thehomogeneous equation with compact initial data on  every given spacelike slice (more properly a Cauchy surface).

Hence, up to mathematical details,  *starting form a Green function $G$ and adding all possible maps $E$ as above we can reach every other Green function.*

However it is difficult to construct a Green function whose integral kernel satisfies your requirement $G(x,y)=0$ is $x$ and $y$ are *timelike* separated (notice that $G_\pm(x,y)$ satisfy the same condition but for $x$ and $y$ *spacelike* separated). My feeling it is that it does  **not** exist, but I do not have a proof and I do not have time to search for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! To clarify: If the differential operator is normally hyperbolic then we can always find retarded and advanced Green's functitons that vanish out of the future/past ligthcone?

Comment: Yes you are right.